# Is the Maffei 1 galaxy gravitationally bound to the Milkway Galaxy?

Tags: cosmology, galaxies

I watched a Kurzgesagt video explaining how the limit human exploration is the local group, because outside galaxies are accelerating away from us faster than the speed of light, (or faster than we could ever hope to reach them, I am not sure which.)

I just read that Maffei 1 is not apart of the local group, but I saw google image diagrams displaying Maffei 1:

[image]

Image Source: [Local Group Galaxies](http://pics-about-space.com/local-group-galaxies-map?p=2)

I don't know if there general radius in which galaxies are no longer gravitational attracted to the Milkyway or Andromeda and will accelerate faster and faster away from us on local group diagrams, or does it not only depend on the distance but mass of the galaxy.

Will the Maffei 1 Galaxy drift further apart from the Milkyway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not part of the local Group, it used to be thought that it was, but it has its own. See  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maffei_1

Not sure it's in the Virgo supercluster, our supercluster. The group is about 10 million light years, the supercluster about 110. The local group is more bound gravitationally, but the supecluster is also bound. I do not know if it's bound enough that the universe expansion, as it is right now, would or would not separate them. Eventually, with accelerated expansion everything gets separated, but that's trillions of years.

Neither group nor supercluster define the distance at which galaxies currently recede at a speed of c. That is the Hubble radius of about 14 billion light years, see Hubble length at

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law

It happens at about a redshift z of 3. The observable universe is about 48 billion light years in radius.

Don't know why the limit of intergalactic travel would be the cluster or supercluster. We still don't know how to get out of the solar system, but the limit of c does not enter in for 14 billion light years.

Answer (score 1):

Anything we observe with $z~<~1$ is in principle reachable. Anything with $z~>~1$ we observe as they were at a time before they crossed the cosmological horizon in the past. At $z~-~1$ $=~v/c$ the velocity of the galaxy by the elementary Hubble rule $v~=~Hd$ the distance of the galaxy is $d~=~c/H$, which is the horizon. With respect to the cosmological constant the cosmological horizon is $r_h~=~\sqrt{3/\Lambda}$, for $\Lambda$ the cosmological constant $\Lambda~\simeq~1.2\times 10^{−52}m^{−2}$. This is also related to the Hubble expansion parameter by
$$
\left(\frac{\dot a}{a}\right)^2~=~H^2~=~\frac{8\pi G\rho}{3c^2}~=~\frac{\Lambda c^2}{3}.
$$
Here $\rho$ is the vacuum energy density that defines so called dark energy driving expansion. The Hubble parameter is about $67km/sec-Mpc$ and the cosmological horizon is at $r_h~\simeq~10^{10}$ light years.

A space traveler with a spacecraft that is able to reach extreme relativistic velocities can reach destination close to the horizon. A galaxy recedes away at
by the Hubble rule $v~=~Hd$. However the galaxy accelerates by the above relationship. So one must factor that into the trip; you need to accelerate to sufficient velocity to reach your destination lest it slip across the horizon and become unreachable.

I have seen the same video, and I think it is making a practical case that the local group, or maybe the Virgo supercluster, is only reachable in principle. Of course intergalactic space travel is likely not practical to begin with. It might be the same with interstellar space travel, it may not be practical. The travel time to different galaxies would be in the millions of years, and it would require a high relativistic boost, with $\gamma~\sim~10^5$ to reduce the proper time of travel on the spacecraft to a human lifetime. To reach very distant galaxies you need much higher relativistic boosts.